# Getting the email count from addressbook

Tags: iphone, ios, email, addressbook

I am trying to get the email count of a contact from addressbook. This is what I tried.

```
ABMultiValueRef email = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonEmailProperty);
NSArray* emails = (NSArray*)ABMultiValueCopyArrayOfAllValues(email);

if([emails count] < 1){
//things to do
}
```

But I am not getting the count right(count is always nil). What am I doing wrong here? Whats the right way to do this?

Comment: Your code looks fine - perhaps something is wrong with your `ABRecordRef` person.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you checked if email is null?

Anyway, this should work:

```
ABMultiValueRef email = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonEmailProperty);
int size = ABMultiValueGetCount(email);
```

Answer (score 0):

The code I have given was right. The problem was someone who gave their email address in the url label which was misleading me all this time, and I could find it only when I tried to edit the addressbook. Apologies for the stupid question. Thank you.